# where's data store after deploy spider scrapyd python?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

i deployed and scheduled my spider on `http://localhost:6800/` success, but where's data of item store ? How could i get them ?

thanks so much !

Comment: Do you have any pipelines configured? Show your `settings.py`.

Comment: Yes, i have a pipiline, if i using command `scrapy crawl myspider`, i run ok and stored data in my json file, but when i deploy my project with comand `curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=project_name -d spider=myspider`, it deploy sucess but i can't not find my data.This is my setting .py :                              `BOT_NAME = 'comicvn2'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['comicvn2.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'comicvn2.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'comicvn2.pipelines.Comicvn2Pipeline'
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it in `process_item()` instead of handle by scrapyd.Because scrapyd just logs items, there is no difference in a way to store data except log file.  You can find it in documentation of scrapyd.

Comment: thanks your help, in process_item(),I  got and saved data in json type. It resolve my prolem.

Answer (score 0):

In scrapyd you have to define item directory in scrapyd.conf file, for more information you can look at scrapyd documentation [scrapyd.conf](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html)